# How to add email address through prompt in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to send a chart created through Excel VBA, But how to add the recepients dynamically through prompt.

`wkbk.SendMail Recipients:="dind_r01@gmail.com"` . here how to add the email address(More than 1 email address) through prompt, instead of defining it in code.

Comment: In that case there are many example in SO which tell how to add recipients to an email :)

Comment: receipients should be added dynamically(eg: inputbox), and the source of receipients is not a worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wk.SendMail Recipients:=Application.InputBox("Please enter email address:", "Email Address", , , , , 2)
```

Comment: Thanks Huy, Its working for 1 email address, hope i will do it for adding more than 1 email address.